# Getting errors while imitating tail command in shell script without using inbuilt tail command

Tags: shell, syntax-error

I have written this code  to imitate tail command without using inbuilt command and it is giving error in for loop though syntax is correct!
I am not able to figure it out where actually the error is?
Also Expected output:
It should print last n number of lines from the file.
n is scanned from user.
[image: Error in Code]

`#!/bin/sh echo -n "Enter file name: " read file_name echo -n "Enter number of lines: " read n touch $file_name str="end" temp="temp" echo "Start entering data of file and write end for stopping: " while [ 1 ] do    read string     touch $temp     echo $string > $temp    grep -w "$str" $temp    if [ $? -eq 0 ]     then        break   else        cat $temp >> $file_name     fi done rm $temp echo "---------------------------------------------------------" total_lines= wc -l < $file_name echo $total_lines a=`expr $total_lines - $n `exec < $file_name for ((i=$a;i<$total_lines;i++ )) do    read a1     echo $a1 done`

Comment: `#!/bin/sh` is not `#!/bin/bash`. The syntax is correct _for bash_, not for sh.

Comment: Please format your script code with newlines to be readable.

Comment: This was formatted only but actually while pasting code it looked ugly. 
Thank you!